# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts work in one file, not in another

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) Build id: M20171130-0510 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

My keyboard preferences are working, behaving properly in one file, but not in another file of that same type. I made a third file to test this behavior, and in the third file my shortcuts work again. All files are in the same environment, and I'm simply talking about the emacs-style navigation key sequences.

What could cause this? Where would I have disabled my keyboard shortcuts on just one file? How would I re-enable them?

Comment: Shortcuts can be editor specific, but not file specific. Select the files, right-click and choose _Open With > ..._ By the way, your Eclipse is pretty old (9 releases behind). Please do not wast time by using outdated software.

Comment: For a number of reasons I am limited to this version (proprietary language tooling.) Thank you, though. Under normal circumstances you'd've probably saved me many headaches.